# find out data, whose predictions are way off

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am using  pandas sklearn to do some price prediction model. I divide the dataset into train and test sets. Then I fit the model and predict. 
X and y are pandas dataframe

```
X_train,X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
difference = np.abs(np.subtract(y_pred,y_test))
```

define own way of calculating accuracy in a percentage way other than mae

```
accuracy=np.divide(np.abs(np.subtract(y_pred,y_test)),y_test)
```

But how can I filter data with lowest accuracy in pandas to explore the data with bad prediction in pandas?

Comment: You can append the predictions and/or difference back onto the dataframe and treat it like any other column. The predictions are in the same order as the data that was predicted on

Comment: `filter(lambda x:x<50, your_numpy_array)`